# How to get pixel color values from a kivy window

Tags: kivy, pixel

I would like get the color of individual pixels with the python library kivy on the screen at the current time. 
A psuedo code example:

```
Window.Getpixel((50, 50))
```

Output:

```
rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
```

Any help with this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [export_as_image()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.export_as_image) to get a [core Image](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.image.html#kivy.core.image.Image) of the `root` of your `App`. Then use [read_pixel(x,y)](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.image.html#kivy.core.image.Image.read_pixel) to get the pixel data

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, [kivy.core.window.WindowBase.screenshot](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html#kivy.core.window.WindowBase.screenshot) is the only function I can find that performs screen capture (which is necessary to extract a pixel). It looks like it writes to a file, so you would then read from that file and take the pixel (messy). Ideally, you'd want to use some other library (other than kivy) such as [pyscreenshot](https://pypi.org/project/pyscreenshot/) (you can use `pycreenshot.grab(bbox=(x, x, x + 1, y + 1))[0, 0]`) or one of its backends (some of which have python wrappers), or [pyscreeze](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze) (you can use `pyscreeze.screenshot(region=(x, x, x + 1, y + 1))[0, 0]`).

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.image import Image
```

insistance on keep_data=True

```
def getPixel(x, y):
    im = Window.screenshot()
    m = Image.load(im, keep_data=True)
    color = m.read_pixel(x, y)
    return color[0] * 255, color[1] * 255, color[2] * 255
```